# How to retrieve work items from Azure DevOps extension?

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I successfully followed [Microsoft's tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-backlog-tabs?view=azure-devops) to create an extension.

I'm trying to get all the work-items of certain sprint, but to be honest, I'm lost...

I'm not sure what to look for - I have the `VSS` object, with which I can `require` additional services (such as `TFS/WorkItemTracking/Services` or `TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient`).

I found some examples like [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/work-item-form/workItemService.html), but couldn't find an API to retrieve or query work items.

Do I need a JS object for that, or is it accomplished via some REST call?

Comment: Are below suggestions what you were looking for? Did it work out?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT they sound just what I was looking for, and I will check them in a week or two (tight schedule...) - I'm very eager to see it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query work items, you can can also check [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2?view=azure-devops) for WorkItemTrackingHttpClient2_2 client API.

```
IPromise<Contracts.WorkItemQueryResult> queryById(id, project, team)

IPromise<Contracts.WorkItemQueryResult> queryByWiql(wiql, project, team)
```

This is also an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/call-rest-api?view=azure-devops#call-an-api) about how to get WorkItemTrackingHttpClient and to call Api on Microsoft docs site.

Answer (score 4):

You are nearly there.

You need the WIT RestClient (assuming you are using Typescript):

```
import { WorkItemTrackingHttpClient, getClient } from "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient";
```

With that you can do

```
const witClient = ((getClient()) as WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
```

and then

```
const result = await witClient.queryByWiql({ query: query });
```

The `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` is all you need to manipulate work items.

EDIT: You could also have a look at the new [SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk) and [API](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api). But unfortunately its lacking a lot on the documentation side. Although there are some [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample).

Comment: can i use this API to get WorkItems from Azure DevOps Extension?: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api