# Azure DevOps rest API's getWorkItems is not returning all available fields

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60813936/azure-devops-api-not-returning-all-fields-for-workitems) came closest to what I'm facing, but their solution doesn't do the trick. Also it's 2.5 years old, so maybe there've been some changes on the API so I'm opening a new question.

Here's my manifest:

```json
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
    }
  ],
  "scopes": [
    "vso.work_full",
    "vso.project_manage",
    "vso.profile",
    "vso.graph",
    "vso.identity"
  ],
  "categories": [
    "Azure Boards"
  ],
  "demands": [
    "api-version/6.0"
  ],
...
  "contributions": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
      "targets": [
        "ms.vss-work-web.work-hub-group"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and my code:

```js
import { getClient } from 'azure-devops-extension-api';
import { WorkItem, WorkItemExpand, WorkItemTrackingRestClient } from 'azure-devops-extension-api/WorkItemTracking';

export class WorkItemsService {
  ...
  static async getWorkItems(ids: number[], projectId: string): Promise<WorkItem[]> {
    const client = getClient(WorkItemTrackingRestClient);
    ...
    client.getWorkItems(ids.slice(...), projectId, undefined, undefined, WorkItemExpand.All));
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm:

1. using the WorkItemTrackingRestClient's `getWorkItems` method [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715799/how-to-retrieve-work-items-from-azure-devops-extension)
2. setting `WorkItemExpand.All` in the request
3. not listing any field names in the request
4. setting `vso.work_full` in the manifest [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60813936/azure-devops-api-not-returning-all-fields-for-workitems)

However I'm only getting these fields back:

```
"System.Id": "",
"System.AreaId": "",
"System.AreaPath": "",
"System.TeamProject": "",
"System.NodeName": "",
"System.AreaLevel1": "",
"System.Rev": "",
"System.AuthorizedDate": "",
"System.RevisedDate": "",
"System.IterationId": "",
"System.IterationPath": "",
"System.IterationLevel1": "",
"System.IterationLevel2": "",
"System.WorkItemType": "",
"System.State": "",
"System.Reason": "",
"System.AssignedTo": "",
"System.CreatedDate": "",
"System.CreatedBy": "",
"System.ChangedDate": "",
"System.ChangedBy": "",
"System.AuthorizedAs": "",
"System.PersonId": "",
"System.Watermark": "",
"System.CommentCount": "",
"System.Title": "",
"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate": "",
"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate": "",
"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy": "",
"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority": "",
"System.Parent": ""
```

But interestingly when I put the URL from the `ApiWorkItem._links.fields` in a browser I get a humongous data set with all the fields I'm interested in and then some, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61900733/how-to-get-custom-field-values-on-a-work-item-from-devops-api). Case in point, `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.xxxx`. In the native method's data it's nowhere to be seen but in the JSON returned by the URL there's a bunch of fields.

When instead of `undefined` I put for example `Effort` as in `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort`, like so

```js
client.getWorkItems(ids.slice(...), projectId, ['Effort']);
```

the results' fields turn out empty.

I don't feel like making hundreds of API calls to get the data I need from the work items' URLs. What am I missing?

I appreciate anyone who read this far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question to prevent wasting anyone else's time. A couple observations that contributed to the perfect storm of misunderstanding:

1. Azure only returns fields that have data
2. `ApiWorkItem._links.fields` only lists **declared fields** in the project and provides no data
3. `getWorkItemsBatch` and `getWorkItems` are two sides of the same coin, returning same set of data
4. in the `fields` parameter of said methods the field's full `referenceName` is required, e.g. `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate` and not just `OriginalEstimate`
5. and most importantly one has to make sure they check against a work item that *actually has* data in the fields they need

Everything works as intended..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to use this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/workitemtrackingrestclient#azure-devops-extension-api-workitemtrackingrestclient-getworkitems

- This method returns only core fields.
- WorkItemExpand.All expands only references (links to other work items, definitions) of a work item.
- I think, the method is based on the following rest API: [Get Work Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-items-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

You can find a raw sample of using it ([Get list of work items for specific fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-items-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#get-list-of-work-items-for-specific-fields)):

```
{
  "ids": [
    297,
    299,
    300
  ],
  "fields": [
    "System.Id",
    "System.Title",
    "System.WorkItemType",
    "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork"
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for Your reply! I have tested `getWorkItemsBatch` again, but am sad to report it behaves the same way for me. Setting `WorkItemBatchGetRequest.fields` to `['Effort']` produces an empty object, while `[]` returns the same set of fields as in my OP.